# How to update Parse to latest version?

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, parse-platform

After installing iOS 8 on my iPhone, the app I was working on with Parse v1.3.0 just stopped working.

I want to update my iOS XCode Project to v.1.4.1. However, as I installed Parse using CocoaPods, I am at a lost on how to update the project to v1.4.1 using Parse iOS SDK, as the latest version is not yet available on CocoaPods.

The Parse iOS SDK comes with 3 folders, Bolts.framework, Parse.framework, ParseFacebookUtils.framework. I can only find Parse.framework in my project folder and the rest of the pods files are in a mess. Do I just delete and replace the Parse.framework folder in my current project and what do I do with the Bolts.framework and ParseFacebookUtils.framework?

Would be grateful if anyone can help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is easier, so long as all active dev projects use the same up-to-date frameworks, to place them in one central area, and then add framework references from within Xcode to that central location. This is what i do, and it works like a charm, without pods.